# What does the "=>" symbol mean in ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I referred to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) documentation on the ionic site, to integrate firebase with my mobile application.

```
this.firebase.getToken()
  .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`)) // save the token server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
  .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));

this.firebase.onTokenRefresh()
  .subscribe((token: string) => console.log(`Got a new token ${token}`));
```

As seen in the above code, the `'then'`, `'catch'` and `'subscribe'` methods seem to have a variable followed by the `"=>"` symbol. Does this symbol have a generic meaning or does it vary from method to method? What exactly does it mean?

EDIT: Since this question is marked duplicate by others, I thought it was a new feature in typescript that I was not aware of. In JavaScript, I had always used the old school method as pointed in one of the answers. It might help others like me, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lambda expression, which is basically a function that is passed as an argument to methods such as `then` and `subscribe`, and is called by those methods once they receive an emission.

token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`)

It's a function that takes a token as argument, and logs it.

The argument is passed by the `then` function, when it invokes your lambda expression. If that makes sense?